# at/on/in a more general level?

Tags: phrases, expressions, expression-choice

Which one is correct?

> at/in/on a more general level

having discussed some implications of my theory for some particular debates, now I want to talk about one more general broadly important implication of it. Should I start the sentence with at/on/in a more general level?

According to Ngram the expression with "at" is more popular while it is not used as all with "in". [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20a%20more%20general%20level%2C%20on%20a%20more%20general%20level%2C%20at%20a%20more%20general%20level&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20more%20general%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20more%20general%20level%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

Based on personal experience, here's what I think:

"On a more general level" means "basically," so use "on" when speaking to an audience less educated on your specific topic because the audience's knowledge is less specialized.

"At a more general level" means "generally," so use "at" to explain that the concept can be generalized. This is what you should use.